# difference between two ways of division in c++

Tags: c++

what is the difference between

```
int n,s;
cin>>n;
s=n*1/10;
cout<<s;
```

and

```
int n,s;
cin>>n;
s=n*10/100;
cout<<s;
```

?

and also 100/1000 and 1000/10000 and ...

when I enter big numbers for n(such as 1000000000),it has different outputs.

---

I got my answer!!

the problem is because of order of evaluation and also overflowing in integer

Comment: You are aware how integer division works? `cin>>;` is bogus BTW.

Comment: The difference is 1 versus 10. What exactly is your question? What is the problem you are trying to solve? Please post a full example that compiles.

Comment: Hint: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Another hint: arithmetic overflow.

Comment: the latter is more prone to overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a large number and multiply by 10, the number may overflow.  This means that the number that you're trying to store is too big to fit into the memory allocated for that number.  The exact consequence for a signed integer overflowing is called "undefined behaviour" meaning that it's up to the compiler to decide how to deal with this.

When you divide by 100, the number you're dividing is now different than the number than you're expecting - thus giving you the wrong result.

This is likely only a problem on debug builds; as the compiler will probably replace the *10/100 to be /10 as part of the optimisation that it will do for a release build.

The other item where you multiply by 1 and then divide by 10 will always be defined however, since the multiplication will leave the number unchanged.